# Multithreading throws org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I keep getting this error when I try to use multithreading (no problem if I run the program sequentially) in this service:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Service {

    private final Repository repository;

    public List<A> getAs(String[] ids) {
        List<A> as = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

        List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String id : ids) {
            futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> repository.findById(id).orElse(null)).thenApply(as::add));
        }

        futures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);

        return as;
    }

}
```

`Repository` is a standard `JpaRepository<A, String>` and `A`:

```
public class A {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b")
    private B b;

}
```

The error is thrown when executing `A#getB` on any element of the returned list

Comment: Add @Transactional annotation above into your getAs method

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov already tried and it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Because B is Lazy loaded.

1. You can make this part **in transaction** and add init query:

```
repository.findById(id).map(v -> {v.getB(); return v;}).orElse(null))
```

2. Or you can use create not lazy query:

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, String> { 
    @Query(value = "SELECT c FROM A c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.b where c.id = :id")   
    A findById(@Param("id") String id);
}
```